# .htaccess rewrite rules working on Mac Apache 2.2 but not on CentOS Apache 2.4

Tags: htaccess, apache, mod-rewrite, centos, mac

I've run into an issue when moving from a test server to a production server.  I have a set of `.htaccess` rules in a file in the `public_html` site root:

```
#Root directory htaccess
RewriteEngine On    # Turn on the rewriting engine

#Rewrite rules for purchase areas
RewriteRule ^purchase\/(\S+) purchase.php?product=$1 [NC,L] #Purchase a named product
RewriteRule ^purchase purchase.php [NC,L] #Purchase page
```

On my test server, these work perfectly loading the correct page each time.

On the production server, everything after the first slash seems to be ignored and a 404 is given. The other `.htaccess` rules work fine, it just seems to be ones with two levels that don't work as expected.

What have I done wrong, and what can I do to make this consistent?

- Test Server document root `http://localhost:8888/` Apache/2.2.34 (MAMP)
- Live Server document root `https://example.com/` Apache/2.4.6 (CentOS)

---

**First update**

I have spent a good few hours on this now and in a bout of frustration deleted my `.htaccess`. I was very surprised to see that some redirects were still working - and it turns out my `.htaccess` file was doing absolutely nothing aside from custom errors.

Currently, wherever a PHP file exists with a matching name to the URL are opened directly - without any `.htaccess` in the directory - eg:

With no `.htaccess` in the directory:

- `https://example.com/purchase` opens `purchase.php`
- `https://example.com/foo` opens `foo.php`
- `https://example.com/bar` gives a 404 as `bar` isn't a file in this directory.

Is this typical Apache behaviour or is there a rule in a different config I need to track down and override?

Comment: Apache 2.2 and 2.4 are very different servers.   Can you upgrade your test server to 2.4?   I don't know of any big differences specifically with mod_rewrite, but I had to make many configuration changes when I upgraded a few years ago:  https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/upgrading.html       In general this is why you want to do your testing on a machine that is as close to possible as your production server.    Using a different OS and version of Apache is just a disaster waiting to happen.

Comment: Yep, pointless testing locally if they are not identical setups.

Comment: @StephenOstermiller Yeah, it's rather caught me out that a new install of MAMP isn't up to date with Apache versions - I'll move to a virtual machine running the same system in future.  I will also look through the change log and see if I can find anything breaking

Comment: The URLs working without the extension is caused by the [Multiviews](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/content-negotiation.html#multiviews) option, which is compiled into Apache by default and can be enabled and disabled per directory with `Options Multiviews` or  `Options -Multiviews`

Comment: Whether or not .htaccess takes effect is controlled by [AllowOverride](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/mod/core.html#allowoverride)

Comment: You should also check that mod_rewrite is installed and loaded: https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-set-up-mod_rewrite-for-apache-on-centos-7

Comment: @StephenOstermiller & Simon thank you both for sticking with me there - you definitely gave me the knowledge to find my answer

Answer (score 1):

So I eventually worked this out by going line to line changing redirects to https://google.com to see which worked and which didn't.  Any patterns in the .htaccess that had a matching php file wouldn't load.

I think it's a configuration difference between the two rather than a version difference and was fixed immediately in my case by adding `Options -MultiViews` to the top of my .htaccess file.  They then all worked as expected - perhaps multiviews was disabled on my test server.

Comment: Yes, this is simply a config difference, not a difference in the Apache version. `MultiViews` is not enabled by default on any version of Apache. So, for some reason, it has been _explicitly_ enabled on your "production server".